# Google Places Web Api

Tags: react-native

I am working on a project to create a Uber clone. I will need to have a text input which will list predicted addresses like in the actual Uber app when user types in the text input. Once user selects the location, a map will be automatically updated.

Can I achieve this using the Google places web api alone, without touching native code? I know this can be achieved using react native google places (which needs to touch native code) but I am not comfortable toying with native codes.

If possible to achieve using Google places web api, anyone can share samples of how this is done? Tutorials online only show how to set markers for certain types only eg hotels which is not what I want to achieve. I m not sure what is the 'type'  I should set when using Google places web api.

I use react native init to initialize my react native app

Thanks

Comment: You probably need a react-native version of it. react-native runs natively and does not have access to the browser window which maybe used in the web api.

Comment: Thanks for response. However I thought we can make a fetch call to the Google web apis and then use the response to populate options to our users? I might have found the googleapis link. Ll give it a try. Let ya know if I can make it work